# Retrofit Fan box for horizontal 2x4 truss

Tags: ceiling-fan

I am attempting to install a [retrofit fan brace](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-15-3-cu-in-Remodel-Construction-Ceiling-Fan-Brace-with-1-1-2-in-Box-CMB150-OB/205383178#product-overview) and ran into an issue where my 2x4 are horizontal and not vertical, what are my options to support a fan or are there alternative braces for this setup? (also if any of the wording is inaccurate based on the picture please update/comment)

[image]

**Answer**

I ended up using 3 screws a top 2x4 and a sideways 2x4 and screwed into the brace, seems very stable but I noted it for only a light or lightweight fan (for now it's just a pool table light anyway) and then used the retrofit kit, which secured nicely (I hung on it for a few seconds at 150lbs)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take Ecnerwal's suggestion a bit further. Build some simple blocks with flanges using 2x3 (so they fit through the hole) and plywood (whatever you have on hand). Drop them in place with beads of construction adhesive or wood glue on the backs. Come back a day later and carry on.

```
SIDE (ELEVATION) VIEW
     ____ ______________________
    |    |                      |
    |----|-------- <--screws    |<-- new 2x3 block
    |    |                      |
   ||----|--------              |
   ||    |______________________|_____ <-- glue joint
   ||    |                            |
 __||    |                            |
   ||    |<-- glue joint              |
 __||    |                            |<-- truss chord
   ||____|____________________________|
       ^-- plywood

TOP (PLAN) VIEW
     ____ ____________________________
    |    |                      |     |
    |    |                      |     |
    |----|--------              |     |
    |    |                      |     |
   ||    |                      |     |
   ||    |                      |     |
___||    |                      |     |
   ||    |                      |     |
___||    |                      |     |
   ||    |                      |     |
   ||    |                      |     |
   ||    |                      |     |
    |    |                      |     |
    |----|--------              |     |
    |    |                      |     |
    |____|______________________|_____|
```

Comment: I went with all 2x4's but basically this layout. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Screw a short chunk of 2x4 to the top of the bottom chord so you have enough wood for the brace to grab.

Comment: like this? - https://imgur.com/qT9q6AI

Comment: Not quite - that looks (to me) like it's set to the side of the lower truss chord. I'm proposing stacking a short chunk of 2x4 right on top of the lower piece of 2x4 forming the truss, giving you extra thickness at the point you want the fan box.

Comment: that kind of defeats the purpose of the retrofit brace,

Comment: @Ecnerwal I have a 2x4 on top and in front to hold it, remember I have to do all of this via a 4" hole so it's very tight, can't seem to get the screws in so I'm planning to try some SPAX 2' tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

get some 2x4 (or 1x4) about as long as the truss is high and put some 2"or 2.5" nails through each end (so they stick out a bit)

pass it up through the hole and with it vertical press it against the side of the truss where the brace will contact the truss.  it may be possible to screw it to the top part of the truss using a long driver

put the brace up and tighten it against the 2x4.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't give much lateral support, meaning the fan could vibrate the blocks sideways.

Comment: no because the nails will hold  it - same as the spikes on the brace hold it

Comment: I see what you're saying now. You might revise to make that more clear. Also locate your missing Shift key and sprinkle a few more periods in there. :)